# boost::bind and delete 

Tags: c++, boost, bind

I need to map a `delete ptrAddr;` to a `boost::function0` but i have some troubles doing that for delete. free works just fine. The issue appears to be `std::ptr_fun(operator delete)` but i can't figure how to make this work without writing a helper functor.

```
boost::function0<void> Function;
Function = boost::bind(std::ptr_fun(free), (void*)malloc_string);  //this works
Function = boost::bind(std::ptr_fun(operator delete), (void*)new_string);  //doesn't work
Function();  //call function
```

Comment: there's a hidden this pointer when dealing with the user defined types. also it calls destructor before deleting the allocated memory. Don't mix new/delete with malloc/free

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`delete_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.construction_and_destruction) from Boost.Lambda:

```
boost::bind(boost::delete_ptr(), new_string);
```

In C++11, you can use `std::default_delete<T>`:

```
std::bind(std::default_delete<decltype(new_string)>(), new_string);
```

Or just a lambda:

```
[new_string]() { delete new_string; }
```

Comment: should I make the allocation via `new_ptr` in order to use `delete_ptr` ?

Comment: @cprogrammer: No, `new_ptr` is defined to use `new T(args)`, and `delete_ptr` is defined to use `delete T`, because well, it doesn't make much sense to do otherwise.

Comment: any idea why I receive bind.hpp(69) : error C2039: 'result_type' : is not a member of 'boost::lambda::delete_ptr' ?

Comment: I was using boost/bind instead of boost/lambda/bind. thanks cat

Answer (score 4):

`delete p;` is not a function call; it's an **expression**. What you want doesn't make sense.

There does exist a free function `::operator delete()`, but that doesn't do what you think.

Look at the implementation of any standard library container (keyword: allocator), or perhaps `std::unique_ptr`, to see how one handles customizable object deletion.

---

The typical construction/destruction sequence broken down into pieces looks like this:

```
void * addr = ::operator new(sizeof(T));  // allocation

T * p = ::new (addr) T;                   // construction

p->~T();                                  // destruction

::operator delete(addr);                  // deallocation
```

The first to steps are morally equivalent to the *expression* `T * p = new T;`, while the last to correspond to `delete p;`. There is no way to call a constructor other than through a `new` *expression*, though; and you mustn't forget to invoke the destructor one way or another.